# Creating log files with a version history

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that works with ten text files and creates a log file for each of them after a successful operation.

But if I run the script again, it will override any existing log files.

How can I implement some version control for backup purposes, so that new log files can be can be created without overwriting the previous ones if the script is run again?

I am thinking of generating a time stamp every time the script is run but not sure whether this is efficient.

Comment: An easy solution would be to build upon an existing version control system like git. Otherwise, the time stamp idea is a good one – just append an ISO file stamp (modified to avoid `:`) to the file name: `2014-04-28T23-03-00.foo.log`, which has the convenient effect that sorting the logs alphabetically also implies a sorting by time.

Comment: It depends very much on how you want to access your log files. There is no problem with *"generating a time stamp every time the script is run"*, certainly with respect to efficiency, but will the resulting file names allow you to access the data in a useful way?

Answer (score 2):

[`Log::Dispatch`](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aDispatch) or [`Log::Log4perl`](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aLog4perl) could be used to access features like this.

Specifically you could use `Log::Dispatch::File::Rolling` or `Log::Dispatch::File::Stamped`

Comment: An example would be very useful. As it is, you have said little more than *"Perl could be used to do this"*. +1 anyway in anticipation of a fuller answer, as I'd prefer to see a modularised solution

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to make the logging operation append instead of overwrite.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '>>', 'file.log';
```

Alternatively, you could backup old logs using an incrementor before a rerun.  Can't say I'd be thrilled with this solution though.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Copy qw(move);
use List::Util qw(max);

my $log = 'file.log';

my $maxid = 1 + max map {/(\d+)$/ ? $1 : 0} <$log.*>;
move($log, "$log.$maxid");

open my $fh, '>', $log;
```